# App won't run on iPhone after denying keychain access

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a problem with my app. 
After adding certificates for using remote Push Notifications I wanted to test it on my iPhone (7S). Than xCode asked me for keychain access. But I had forgotten my password, so I denied it and looked it up. Than I tried to rerun the app, but xCode crashes every time with the same error (see bellow). I tried restarting xCode, removing my account from Xcode and add it again, deleting certificates and download it again... But nothing worked. Hopefully somebody can help...

Here the Errorcode:

```
Probing signature of /Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
/Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '7319A6E748656B8031B1B216ED08967067862C10' '--verbose' '/Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
/Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '7319A6E748656B8031B1B216ED08967067862C10' '--verbose' '/Users/<MYNAME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CBG-App-cbcnuiuwufasepbebirhstwqwkst/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CBG-App.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
}
```

Comment: In most cases when I got this kind of error, I had to delete WWDR certificate and install it again from here. http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem last weak its a pain in the a..

Solution:

1- Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist

2- Reboot

3- Solved!

PD: if still complains just download the provisional profile again or if automatic then change to none and back to yours again.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Xcode access to your cert.  Open KeyChain and find your certificate.  Right click on the certificate and select "Get Info".  Click the "Access Control" tab and add Xcode.app

Answer (score 0):

I solved by my self. 
Restarting the Mac and Clearing Xcode helped. After that I had to fill in the password about a hundred times, but now it works.
Thank you anyway for answering!